# Creating an NSDate based on later date

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, datetime

I am trying to create an NSDate object with a certain number of hours and minutes before a reference date.

For example:

```
Reference date = oct 21 2013 12:30 PM

date with 2 hours before and 40 minute before: oct 21 2013 9:50 AM
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSDate method dateByAddingTimeInterval. It takes a NSTimeInterval double to add the number of seconds to the desired time. Check NSDate class, there are other method of interest for you. [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: But i don't want to add a time interval, I want to subtract one. Would it work if i made it a negative number?

Comment: @user2113952: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes also it says in the documentation

Comment: I was looking for a method like dateBySubtractingTimeInterval: and didnt think of using a negative number

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSDateComponents`.

```
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSCalender currentCalender] components:(NSDayCalenderUnit | NSMonthCalenderUnit | NSYearCalenderUnit | NSHourCalenderUnit | NSMinuteCalenderUnit | NSSecondCalenderUnit) fromDate:now];
[dateComps setHour:[dateComps hour]-2]; // Subtract here
[dateComps setMinute:[dateComps minute]-40]; // Subtract here

// You can change all components here as above methods.

NSDate *dateResult=[[NSCalender currentCalender] dateFromComponents:dateComps];

NSLog("%@",dateResult);
```

Comment: This is in fact the better way to do date arithmetic, because it takes into account the vagaries of calendars and time zones.